# Past continuous and past simple

Tags: past-tense

I don't know which sentence is correct.

> She was writing her first novel when she was 19 years old
>
> or
>
> She wrote her first novel when she was 19 years old.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct but have different meanings.

The one with the continuous means that she was engaged in the act when she was nineteen. She might not have finished it until she was, say, 22 or 25. The one with the simple past means she completed a novel when she was nineteen.